# npm install -g @vue/cli @vue/cli-init errors

Tags: node.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am busy setting up NativeScript and I am also adding in Vue.js support for it. Well, I get this error when installing. Should I use --unsafe-perm or is there a better way to do this?

```
npm install -g @vue/cli @vue/cli-init
npm WARN deprecated vue-cli@2.9.6: This package has been deprecated in favour of @vue/cli
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.12.7: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
/usr/local/bin/vue -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js

> fsevents@1.2.9 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.9 and node@10.16.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib' 
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, utime '/Users/chris/.node-gyp/10.16.0'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.16.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v64"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.16.0/bin/node /usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.16.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.16.0/bin/node /usr/local/Cellar/node@10/10.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ @vue/cli@3.10.0
+ @vue/cli-init@3.10.0
updated 2 packages in 42.488s
```

Comment: How did you install npm/node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can solve this problem with `--unsafe-perm` : `npm install -g @vue/cli @vue/cli-init --unsafe-perm`

ref. 
https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues/439#issuecomment-462821780