# unable to install vue on macos using npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

there are a few steps:

1. Use node v10+ instead of v14+.
2. (IMPT) add the following path to `~/.zshrc` (if you are using zsh)

`/Users/[yourUsername]/.npm-packages/bin`

`/Users/[yourUsername]/.npm-global/bin`

3. run `source ~/.zshrc` after modifying the file.

Much thanks to @[kissu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8816585/kissu) and @[Lakindu Hewawasam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14618789/lakindu-hewawasam) !!

-------original question-------

I'm on MacOS 10.15.5, node version v14.15.4, npm version 6.14.10.

I've been getting the error `zsh: command not found: vue`, after trying multiple ways to download Vue.

I first tried `npm install -g @vue/cli`, and it was giving me this error, so I uninstalled and tried again with `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli @vue/cli-init --unsafe-perm` referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441093/npm-install-g-vue-cli-vue-cli-init-errors). Still, it doesn't work:

```
yingjieqiao@Yingjies-MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo npm install -g @vue/cli @vue/cli-init --unsafe-perm
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated vue-cli@2.9.6: This package has been deprecated in favour of @vue/cli
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.12.7: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)

> yarn@1.22.10 preinstall /Users/yingjieqiao/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/yarn
> :; (node ./preinstall.js > /dev/null 2>&1 || true)

/Users/yingjieqiao/.npm-global/bin/vue -> /Users/yingjieqiao/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js

> fsevents@1.2.13 install /Users/yingjieqiao/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fsevents
> node install.js

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node

> core-js@3.8.2 postinstall /Users/yingjieqiao/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon:
> https://opencollective.com/core-js
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> @apollo/protobufjs@1.0.5 postinstall /Users/yingjieqiao/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@apollo/protobufjs
> node scripts/postinstall


> nodemon@1.19.4 postinstall /Users/yingjieqiao/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0


> ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /Users/yingjieqiao/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/ejs
> node ./postinstall.js

Thank you for installing EJS: built with the Jake JavaScript build tool (https://jakejs.com/)

npm WARN @vue/compiler-sfc@3.0.5 requires a peer of vue@3.0.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ @vue/cli@4.5.9
+ @vue/cli-init@4.5.9
added 1367 packages from 714 contributors and updated 1 package in 43.692s
yingjieqiao@Yingjies-MacBook-Pro ~ % vue --version
zsh: command not found: vue
yingjieqiao@Yingjies-MacBook-Pro ~ % npm update -g @vue/cli

yingjieqiao@Yingjies-MacBook-Pro ~ % vue --version
zsh: command not found: vue
yingjieqiao@Yingjies-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

In the warning message, it mentioned "xxx package will break on node v14+" a few times. But I think the download command in the official docs should work regardless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for the comments just below the other answer, you may try adding those

```
export PATH="$PATH:$(yarn global bin)"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.npm-global/bin"
```

to your `~/.zshrc` file since vue-cli is properly installed apparently.

Ofc, `source ~/.zshrc` before trying to call the CLI again.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience the `node` version `10.23.0` works best for myself. So I recommend using this because I have solved errors like this using the version `10.23.0`.

Download here: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/

And then, once you have this version of node installed, run the command `$ npm install vue`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've uninstalled node and reinstalled version 10, this time it is installed without errors but still has a few warning messages. I tried running `npm install -g @vue/cli` and `npm install vue` yet it still gives me `zsh: command not found: vue`

The full output is here:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/14AOLYMDIfk7FP5OWw_siAoWIjd5X93L1n_QtkK7cPrE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: so the vue modules are there in your pc

Comment: maybe we can check if the vue command is added to the path

Comment: since you are on a mac try this command - `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli`

Comment: and then run `vue create first-vue-app`

Comment: if none of that works lets try this option:

First locate the path where the vue.js was installed - `/Users/yourUSERNAME/.npm-packages/bin`

And then we have to add the vue commands to your terminal: 

To do this, open up your bash profile: `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`

Add the vue commands to path: export PATH=$PATH:/Users/[yourUserName]/.npm-packages/bin

Comment: I added `export PATH=/Users/yingjieqiao/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH` to `~/.zshrc` (since the terminal is zsh) and `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/yingjieqiao/.npm-packages/bin` to `~/.bash_profile`, yet it still gives me command not found... also, I tried `cd Users/yingjieqiao/.npm-packages/bin` but it gives me no such file or directory, and when I try search for `vue` using spotlight it shows that it is in `/Users/yingjieqiao/node_modules`

Comment: @LakinduHewawasam stop recommending using `sudo`

Comment: @DanielQiao you should add it to the path using the directory of your node modules for vue

Comment: try and see if that will work @DanielQiao

Answer (score 1):

You should not install any package w/ a `sudo` prefix.
How is your node version installed btw, via `nvm` or manually ?
Maybe try to install it w/ `yarn`.

Best idea would probably be to rollback and try to debug the issues on the [recommended way](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html). Maybe digging into specific issues on the github repo.

Btw, the post you're referencing is an old one so things probably changed in between.

I'm on *Linux* running the following versions (`@vue/cli 4.5.9` is fine too, just upgraded).

[image]

EDIT: Also, this [post](https://johnpapa.net/how-to-use-npm-global-without-sudo-on-osx/) may maybe help somehow.